# Is ajax.beginform updatetargetid is required

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

My requirement is to load a partial view as a modal popup.
On my popup there is a textbox and a verify button.
I need to call a ajax request for verify button.
And show the status accordingly.
This is working fine for me but when i google it, most of the site show that updatetargetid as a parmeter in ajax.beginform.
My question is that **Is ajax.beginform updatetargetid is required ?**

Here is my View.

```
                    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("VerifyDateOfBirth", new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        HttpMethod = "Post",
                        OnSuccess = "Loaded"
                    }))
                {  
                    <div>
                        <label for="dateOfBirth">
                            Date Of Birth
                        </label>
                        <br />
                        @Html.TextBox("dateOfBirth", null, new { @class = "dob", @readonly = "true" })
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" id="btnVerify" value="VerifyDateOfBirth" class="">
                        Verify</button>
                    <span id="verifiedStatus" style="color: Blue; display: none;">* Data Match</span>
                    <span id="notverifiedStatus" style="color: Red; display: none;">* Data Not Match</span>
                }
```

Here is my Javascript

```
function Loaded(data) {
    var enteredDateOfBirth = $("#dateOfBirth").val();
    if (data) {
        var json = data.get_response().get_object();
        if (json != null && json.DOB != "") {
            if (enteredDateOfBirth == json.DOB) {
                //alert('result ' + json.DOB);
                $("#verifiedStatus").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#notverifiedStatus").show();
            }
        }
     }
   }
```

Here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult VerifyDateOfBirth(string dateOfBirth)
    {
        //TODO : Get data from db
        var data = new PremiumCalculationASView 
        {
            DOB = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") //dateOfBirth
        };
        return Json(data);
    }
```

This is working fine for me.
**Is updatedtargetid is required here**

Comment: Is the Ajax.BeginForm block is only updated or the whole view is get posted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UpdatetargetId` is optional parameter.

`UpdatetargetId` is the id of the DOM element which you want to update depending upon repsonse from the server.

If you are returning any `View` or `PartialView` from `controller` using `Ajax.BeginForm`. This DOM element will be updated and will have view content you have returned.

In your case, as far as I know, you wont need to specify `UpdateTargetID`

Comment: Is the Ajax.BeginForm block is only updated or the whole view is get updated ?

Comment: The view you have returned from server will be placed inside that DOM element u have specified id of asynchronously

Comment: I am only return Jason not a view. My question is that the Ajax Option Block inside {HTML Code } only refresh or whole view ?

Comment: As u have returned Json no DOM element is going to be updated. You have specified that in OnSuccess